# Best way to visualize a dependent variable as a function of two other independent variables, each of them is a column of a datafarme?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, data-visualization, contour

What is the best way to visualize a dependent variable as a function of two other independent variables, in which each of them is a column of a datafarme?

```
df= [ A: {0.96, 1.12, 0.93, 1.34, 1.04, 0.92, 1.52}
          B: {55, 62, 58, 64, 70, 71, 66}
          c: {0.66, 0.63, 0.69, 0.71, 0.68, 0.64, 0.69}]
```

`df` is the dataframe of three columns A, B, C:

I would like to plot C as a function of A and B (via contour plot or surf-plot or any other suggestions appreciated)
Please note I have millions of data points that some of them overlaps. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your independent variables are completely separate from each other (ie, for 1 value of ID1 you only have 1 value of ID2), I would guess that a 3-dimentional graph would be a good way to look at this.  Alternatively, you could use a 2-dimensional graph with a "heat"-style color for the second independent variable.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use multiple regression with statsmodels.formula.api, make predictions, and then plot the predictions for a visualization. This syntax allows you to look at multiple independents at once.

```
results = smf.ols('income ~ educ + age', data=samples).fit()
```

This link may be helpful to you: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html

Comment: According to the link is the results same as the output here?  ( results = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()  ) if yes could X and y act like separate columns in my dataframe?